# python multithreading application for fetching messages from rabbitmq

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, rabbitmq

Worker.counter =0
confobj.thread_count =2

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    if(Worker.counter<confobj.thread_count):
      logObject = json.loads(body)
      th=Worker(Worker.counter+1,logObject,confobj,fileobj)
      Worker.counter+=1
      th.start()
    else:
      print("All threads are busy.") 
      time.sleep(2)  
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

  channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
  channel.basic_consume(callback,
                        queu`enter code here`e=confobj.queue)
  channel.start_consuming()
```

I want maxthread should be 2 such that first message is accessed by first thread, second message by second thread, third message by first thread again and so on
And then I want to insert that messages into elastic search without skipping any of messages.

Comment: Post attempt (code) at solving this please

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Process from Multiprocessing and call Process.pid function to get accesss to each process id.

Comment: I want whole python program for it

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process


def square(x):
print(x*x)
print('processID =', current_process())
return x * x


def cube(y):
print(y*y*y)
print('processID =', current_process())
return y * y * y


if __name__ == '__main__':
number = 6
one = Process(target=square, args=(number,))
two = Process(target=cube, args=(number,))

one.start()
two.start()

one.join()
two.join()
```

Here is a simple example of using Process with different functions. Therefore you can call .start() by Process Id. (It's not a complite code. It's just an example for understanding).

Comment: I want to access 4 messages with two threads , what should I do ?

Comment: What does it exactly mean? As i understood, you need sort of a cicle with 3 threads or processes, that use individual thread for every third element of the processed list.